# Phonegap / Ripple emulator. Jquery selectors not working from within object method

Tags: jquery, cordova, ripple

Maybe I'm going crazy but this seems like such a basic thing to be stuck on, I have a basic phonegap app compiling to blackberry at the moment but I want to be able to test it in the ripple emulator, my code is altered here for clarity but please look at the following...

in index.html I have the following initialization code.

```
    function onLoad() {
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                } else {
                    onDeviceReady();
                }
            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use the Cordova API
                var program = new app2();
                program.Login();
            }
    }
```

and in index.js the following simple object.

```
var app2 = function(){
    this.Login = function() {
        alert($("#project_list").html());
        this.LoadContent();
    }

    this.LoadContent = function() {
        alert($("#project_list").html());
    }
}
```

For now there is just a string saying "test" in the project_list element so the expected output should be:

"test"

"test"

And it is everywhere except in the ripple emulator. Ripple output is as follows

"test"

"undefined"

as soon as I call a method in the object it seems to completely lose the DOM, I'm scratching my head at this. Can anyone suggest why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
var app2 = function(){
    var that=this;
    this.Login = function() {
        alert($("#project_list").html());
        that.LoadContent();
    }

    this.LoadContent = function() {
        alert($("#project_list").html());
    }
}
```

As long as you are writing in `javascript` the meaning of `this` is owner of that `this`.
In your case, when you write `this.LoadContent()` within your `this.Login()` function, the owner of `this` in `this.Login()` is the `Login` property of `app2` : `app2.Login`. It is NOT `app2`.

So to get around with this, we'll store `this` variable of `app2` in `var that` by doing `var that = this`. So the variable `that` will always be pointing to `app2`. Owner of that is `app2`.

`that` is member variable of `app2`. So `that` will be accessible to all the other member variables of `app2` including `Login`.

Comment: No luck i'm afraid. While your methods works perfectly in a normal browser mode it still fails when called in the ripple emulator, that's my problem you see, my original code works fine in a regular browser, it even works on the device after a phonegap compile, but in ripple...No dice.

Comment: oh! then I will not be able to help you at this moment... Never worked with `ripple`... Heard it for the first time...